# Custom Actions with privileges

Tags: wix

Hi I have created a MSI installer using WIX. I am having a problem with my custom actions. I have a custom action that fills a text box and it only seems to work when I run the MSI from the command prompt with cmd run as administrator. Is there a connection and how do I run my custom action with privileges. My custom action is run as immediate on a button click. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling a text box shouldn't require any privileges, so from the information you gave, this shouldn't occur. Chances are it does require elevation, say in order to acquire the text it puts in the box, and that's why it's having problems. The UI sequence is only elevated if the .msi is launched from an elevated context. The deferred sequence can be elevated even when the .msi is not, but it will not help with your UI.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will look through my code and see if where I am pulling the text from needs to be elevated. Good explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's some required reading on the subject:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

It took me a few reads to understand it.  Basically you need to sequence a custom action between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize and schedule it for [Deferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with No Impersonation.     You may also need to schedule a custom action for Immediate if you need access to the MSI session.    You

Comment: Hi thanks for that link, nice read..:) I realise i posted incorrect info my custom action is actually on a button click long before the progress dialog. I have another custom action that does something similar and it seems to work ok, it's only this one.

Comment: That's a DoAction ControlEvent which is always immediate.  As MichaelU says, that should never require permission.  I'd have to see what your code does to understand why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I will look through my code and try to detect where it needs the permission.